# How to setOffset() in joomla 3.2.3

Tags: cms, upgrade, date

I am migrating a component from joomla 2.5 to joomla 3.2, I got an error in the method where am using setOffset

```
//old version used in joomla 2.5 

$data->setOffset(JFactory::getConfig()->get('offset'));
```

I referred the Link : http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2

```
//after i  refered the above link i changed my code  like 

if($date === null ) {   
  $date = JFactory::getDate();
  $tz = JFactory::getConfig()->get( 'offset' );

  // new Version 
  $date->setTimezone($tz);

  $date = $date->format( "%Y-%m-%d" );
}
```

but i am getting an error  -

```
DateTime::getTimezone() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given  /example.php on line 5 .
```

Plz need your solution to fix the error

Comment: In your code is no getTimezone() so where is line 5 in example.php? btw, you can use $date = JFactory::getDate('now', $tz);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this Error by passing the object of `DateTimeZone` as a parameter (notice the `$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($tz));` in the code bellow). It's working fine.

```
if($date === null )
{
  $date = JFactory::getDate();
  $tz = JFactory::getConfig()->get( 'offset' );

  $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($tz)); //here!

  $date = $date->format( "Y-m-d" );
}
```